# Gradle: Common Zip task for every subproject

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, multi-project

I have a multi-project gradle build, where all subprojects of root project have common zip task. They should zip some source, depending of the subproject's settings.

First, I configured it in parent `build.gradle`:

```
subprojects { subproject ->
    apply plugin: 'java'
    ...

    task submission(type: Zip) { 
        destinationDir = subproject.buildDir
        archiveName = subproject.name

        from subproject.ext.submissionFiles
    }
}
```

But this does not work with `Cannot get property 'submissionFiles' on extra properties extension as it does not exist`. So i moved the task in each subproject's `build.gradle`, which breaks DRY principle.

I think the problem is that the configuration phase takes place before subprojects are configured. How can I "defer" configuration of this task, so that I only configure `ext.submissionFiles` in subprojects?

Comment: Are the 'submissionFiles' created by another task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're saying that `submissionFiles` is set in the subproject's build.gradle?

There are a few ways of doing it.

Option 1. You could defer the evaluation of `subproject.ext.submissionFiles` by wrapping it in a [closure](https://gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#files(java.lang.Object...)):

```
task submission(type: Zip) { 
    destinationDir = subproject.buildDir
    archiveName = subproject.name

    from ({ subproject.ext.submissionFiles })
}
```

---

Option 2. I think it could be better if you didn't use the intermediate variable (submissionFiles) and directly configured the submission task in the children:

```
// In root
task submission(type: Zip) { 
    destinationDir = subproject.buildDir
    archiveName = subproject.name
}

// In child
submission {
    from("path/to/files")
}
```

Using an intermediate variable like that to move configuration around can make your builds harder to understand connections between tasks.

---

Option 3. In some cases, it makes sense to use [evaluationDependsOnChildren()](https://gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#evaluationDependsOnChildren()), but I would generally not recommend it.

Comment: I like the second variant!

Comment: Problem is, in first example ```from ({ subproject.ext.submissionFiles })``` works, but I can't get ```destinationDir = subproject.buildDir``` to work. Error message is: ```Could not get unknown property 'buildDir' for project ':sub-project-name'.

Surely there must be away to write this in the root projects so the variables are put in at configuration cycle?